# Can you use a css selector reference to an external css module class?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS only menu overlay and have split up my React components with CSS modules.
I found a neat example online that I am trying to implement, and have come across issues applying it in the context of CSS modules, specifically as the example selects another CSS class (which for me is in another module).

HTML

```
<button>☰</button>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button onclick="alert('Hello there!')">
        Display Greeting
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="print()">
        Print This Page
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    visibility: hidden;
}

button + .menu:active,
button:focus + .menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Using this example, I have .menu in module_1, and button in module_2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This may be possible with only CSS. But I would recommend using a CSS preprocessing framework like Sass.

Comment: @TannerDolby, I am using LESS

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying you're using LESS. That was not prefaced in your question, the only reason I asked.